# Execute stored procedure that has parameters with sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that has parameter

```
CREATE Procedure GetSupplierForTesting
    (@SupplierId INT)
AS
    SELECT SuppLabel 
    FROM Supplier 
    WHERE Supplier.SupplierId = @SupplierId
```

I am able to call it with the exec command inside another stored procedure like this

```
exec GetSupplierForTesting @SupplierId = 10
```

I came across an article that explains how `sp_executesql` is faster than `exec`. My problem is that I don't know how to call a stored procedure that has parameters with `sp_executesql`. I have tried this code

```
DECLARE @SupplierId INT = 10;
EXEC sp_executesql N'GetSupplierForTesting', N'@SupplierId INT', @SupplierId
```

but I am getting an error:

> Procedure or function 'GetSupplierForTesting' expects parameter '@SupplierId', which was not supplied

Comment: **Always** run a stored procedure with `EXEC spName` if possible, the performance comments only relate to the `EXEC <SQL string here>` usage of `EXEC` - i.e. if you built an SQL statement into a string or you had a procedure name in a variable.

Comment: And also note you still have ’EXEC` anyway before `sp_executesql` as you are calling *that* stored procedure.

Comment: Can you add the link to the article to your question, it sounds highly unlikely that in any circumstance sp_executesql would be faster way to execute procedures.

Comment: @JamesZ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx, but as Martin Smith explained it is faster only if you built an SQL statement into a string

Comment: Yes the article only means the re-use of query plans -- and that only applies for dynamic SQL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax you would need would be

```
DECLARE @SupplierId INT = 10;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'GetSupplierForTesting @SupplierId=@SupplierId', 
                       N'@SupplierId INT', 
                         @SupplierId=@SupplierId
```

But **don't do this**. It is utterly pointless. There is no magic performance increase to be expected from using `sp_executesql` to basically wrap the same `exec` statement and execute it at a different scope.

Just use

```
exec dbo.GetSupplierForTesting @SupplierId = 10
```

Comment: The sad thing is that there is not error/warning info for this kind of "mistakes" `@SupplierId=@SupplierId`

Answer (score 2):

## 1

Performance issue is based on assumption that when you are using non-parametrized ad-hoc query, it (the string representing this query) will be different every time - because specific argument values are parts of query text.

Whilst parametrized query keeps it's body unchanged because in place of `where ... and title="asdf"` you have `where ... and title = @title`. Only contents of variable `@title` change. But query text persists and sql server realizes that there is no need to recompile it.

Non-parametrized query will be recompiled every time you change values used in it.

## 2

You are getting exception because your script does not pass any arguments to the stored proc.

Your script is: `'GetSupplierForTesting'` - that's it.

By passing arguments to `sp_executesql` you are passing them to the scipt. Not to the sp used in script, but to the script itself. E.g.:

```
exec sp_executesql N'print @val', N'@val int', @val = 1
```

this script does utilize variable @val. Your - does not. It just contains name of the proc. So your script corrected should look like

```
exec sp_executesql
    N'exec GetSupplierForTesting @Supplier = @Supplier_id_value', 
    N'@Supplier_id_value int',
    @Supplier_id_value = 10
```

1. script contains code calling your sp and this code passes argument to sp with value taken from `@Supplier_id_value` variable
2. `@Supplier_id_value` is declared as int for internals of this script
3. value of `10` is passed to the *argument of the **script***

## 3

Performance issue you are talking about is about ad-hocs, not SPs.

Another face of this issue is *parameter sniffing* problem. Sometimes with specific param values your script or SP should use another execution plan, different from the plan it used for previously passed param values.

*Every time recompiled* ("slowly executed") ad-hoc would be (re)compiled for sure and probably would get better execution plan while SP or parametrized query would probably not be recompiled and would use worse, less optimal execution plan and would finally perform much slower than "slow because of recompilation" ad-hoc query.

There are no "write this - and it will work slowly", "write that - and it will hurtle like a rocket" rules in sql. It all depends on many factors. Sometimes one would probably need specifically ad-hocs, sometimes - should avoid them totally.